# PHP, проверить существует ли такая дата

Tags: php, дата

у меня есть данный код

```
public function validationApiGetDataFromTo($from, $to)
    {
        if ($this->is_Date($from) === true and $this->is_Date($to) === true) {
            return true;
            //TODO существует ли такая дата
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function is_Date($str)
    {
        return is_numeric(strtotime($str));
    }
```

Но при таком вводе `http://localhost/rest/all/V1/api/orders/?from=31.01.2020&to=2213213` мне нужно понять существует ли такая дата

как сделать правильную валидацию и также для разных форматов даты
как `y-m-d`, `y-d-m`, `'d-m-y'` и т.д

Comment: Создать новый объект `DateTime`.

Comment: да, но ему нужно указать формат, а их много
Как правильно это реализовать использовав минимальное количество строк?

Comment: А что означает `проверить существует ли такая дата`. Значение даты `$from, $to` с чем хотите сравнить?

Comment: к примеру пришла дата 32.01.2020 -> такой даты не существует
также я смотрю по формату y-m-d, а формат пришел d-m-y
все это мне нужно проверить 
чтобы не зависило в каком формате пришла данная нужно понять - существует ли она

Comment: В конструкторе `Datetime` нет никакого формата. В него можно скормить строку и он попытается ее разобрать и превратить в дату.

Comment: да, но к примеру дату 32.02.2020 он переобразует в 03.02.2020 года,а мне нужно чтобы сказало что такой даты не существует

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере две неточности, во-первых вы проверяете на `true` `===` вы наверно забыли, что при таком сравнении едёт жёсткая типимизация. Всего то вам надо проверять на пустоту.   В вашем примере вы меняете формат даты через `strtotime()` это правильно, но (во-вторых) нет смысла использовать `is_numeric`. Обратите внимание, если вы передаёте некорректную дату в данный метод, то она просто ничего не возращает. Можете попробовать так:

```
public function validationApiGetDataFromTo( $from, $to ) {
    if ( !empty( $this->is_Date( $from ) ) and !empty( $this->is_Date( $to ) ) {
            return true;

        } else {
            /*
             Одна(или оба) из значений некорректны
            */
        }

        return false;
    }


    public  function is_Date( $str ) {
        return strtotime( $str );
    }
```

и не важно каким форматом вы получаете дату, если она некорректна вы (т.е `strtotime()`) поймаете её :)

Comment: но здесь зависит от формата
если будет формат m-d-y -> уже работать будет не так как нужно
здесь дело в формате
к примеру 25.02.2020 -> d-m-Y
и 02.25.2020 -> m-d-Y
мне нужно рассматривать все возможные форматы

Comment: @DenysMaksiura а с чего вы взяли, что для `strtotime()` формат 02.25.2020 некорректен ? данный метод прекрастно справляется со всеми форматами даты. Вы хоть проверили мой пример?